# How to work bluetooth with asus eeepad?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, 3.0-honeycomb, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Odd question.. How do I get my bluetooth headset to handle the audio/mic for my tablet?

Comment: You should tell as what you tried already. Didn't pairing work?

Comment: I paired it then audio wasnt playing through the headset, it was still playing through the tablet. And I tried an sip handling program and the audio/mic was still going through the tablet and not the headset..